# Ember Select set content binding

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a decently complex setup with Ember using a nested View/template inside of a greater View. My parent view has a Controller with an array on it that I would like to use as the contentBinding of my Select within the inner View/template.

I've gotten the handlebars helper to work within my inner template but I also wanted to extend  the Select programmatically to add some validation styling support. When I extend the Ember.Select however and set the contentBinding it doesn't take.

Example in my template:

```
{{view Ember.Select 
       prompt="Choose" 
       classNames="span12" 
       contentBinding="view.parentView.controller.countrylist" 
       optionLabelPath="content.name" 
       optionValuePath="content.id" 
       selectionBinding="view.parentView.controller.selectedObject"
       valueBinding="view.parentView.controller.model.state"}}
```

And as a View that I display with {{view view.selectBox}}, I set selectBox to SelectBoxView.

```
SelectBoxView = Ember.Select.extend({
    prompt: "Please Choose",
    contentBinding: 'parentView.controller.countrylist',
    selectionBinding: 'parentView.controller.selectedObject',
    optionLabelPath: 'content.name',
    optionValuePath: 'content.id',
    classNames: ["span12"]
```

Both Selects show up but only the pure handlebars one has data to show. I've tried every combination I can think of to reach the countrylist in my outer View's Controller.

Edit:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oxAluJI/2/edit?html,js,output

Okay, I messed with this all this morning. The problem I have is getting the countries from a 'parent' controller. I don't have one for the view I'm in and thought I could get around making one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to hardcode in the bindings like that, it is bad practice.  Especially since they are going out of their scope looking for values.  Pass the country list array down into the view, and attach it when you create an instance of the selector.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/alAQEgux/3/edit

```
App.AppleView = Em.View.extend({
  templateName: 'apple'
});

App.SelectBoxView = Ember.Select.extend({
    prompt: "Please Choose",
    optionLabelPath: 'content',
    optionValuePath: 'content',
    classNames: ["span12"]
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{view App.AppleView countryList=model}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="apple">
  Apples
  {{view App.SelectBoxView contentBinding=view.countryList}}
</script>
```

Comment: This makes sense but I do not have a model at the AppleView 'level'. Put another way, there isn't a defined controller.

I have a route, controller, and view for the upper level. The route supplies a model I'm filling out and the controller has the countries list I want to use. The inner View has a template where I'm rendering my Select with a {{view}} helper.

In this example I'll still have to use countryList=parentView.model or something like that to access it, or am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: Would you mind updating my example and showing me an example?